# SIOCADDRT error: no such process

Tags: linux, process, route, gateway

I get this error while configuring a network in Virtual Box with Linux.

I have 2 gateways (192.168.10.5 and 192.168.20.5) that are connected to 2 hosts. The first first host has address 10.0.10.100 and is connected to the gw via 10.0.10 1 while the other has 10 0 20 100 and is connected to the other gw via 10.0.20.1.

The gw are connected via host only network adapters. I have configured the hosts as gw with ip forward.

I make 10.0.10.1 and 10.0.20.1 default gateway for the two hosts. Then my idea was to route add (from 192.168.10.5) net 10.0.20.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.20.5 but I got that error. Can not understand why. Do you have any solution?

[image: Hope it is better]

Comment: The gateway has to be on the same network as the client. If you're on 192.168.10.5, the gateway to get to 10.0.20.x has to have a 192.168.10.x address.

Comment: But I can ping from one gw to the other.

Comment: That's because you have a route to the other gateway. But Linux doesn't do recursive route lookup -- it won't use a gateway to get to a gateway. You have to tell it the first gateway to send to.

Comment: Ok, so from 10.0.10.x i have to add net 10.0.20.x through 10.0.10.1?

Comment: It would help if you showed a diagram of how everything is connected.

Comment: @Barmar, did it now :)

Comment: It's almost unreadable.

Comment: Can you redo it with a darker pen or on a plain white paper. Better would be to use a graphics editor, or plain text.

Comment: Tried to highlight the addresses now

Comment: You don't have any common network between the gateways, unless you have a /16 netmask on the 192.168.x.x interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tunnel between the gateways needs to be a common network.

One way would be to set its network mask to `255.255.0.0`, so that all `192.168.x.x` addresses are on the same network.

If you want to keep the `255.255.255.0` network mask, both gateways need to have `192.168.10.x` (or `192.168.20.x`) addresses.